# What is the size of a bitmap image which is 80px by 70px with 16 different colors?

Tags: bmp

This is a question in my coursebook and the answer says 2800 bytes.

I have not been able to find anything on how to calculate this.

Comment: That is only the size of the "bitmap" part of the 'size'. For a BMP file (as suggested by your tag), you have a larger *file* size because it must also store the header and color table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing it would work like this

70*80 = 5600

Since each pixel can be one of 16 colours, each pixel can be fit in 4 bits (16 number combinations)

Therefore, you divide 5600 by 2 (8 bits in a byte) and get 2800!

Answer (score 1):

It's `(70 * 80 * 4) / 8` which gets you the 2800 bytes.

The explanation is simple enough. You've got `70 * 80 == 5600` different bits in your image. Those bits can be either one of the 16 colours. To store the possiblity of 0-15, we need 4 bits, that lead to `2^4 == 16` combinations.

So `(70 * 80 * 4)` will give you the filesize in bits, divide that by 8 (8 bits in a byte) and you've got your result.